# how can I boot from usb device in libvirt qemu machine?

Tags: libvirt, qemu, usb-flash-drive, usb-boot

I pass-through a usb device like this:

```
<hostdev mode="subsystem" type="usb" managed="yes">
  <source>
    <vendor id="0x067b"/>
    <product id="0x2731"/>
    <address bus="2" device="11"/>
  </source>
  <alias name="hostdev0"/>
  <address type="usb" bus="0" port="4"/>
</hostdev>
```

If I boot from virtual cdrom, the lsusb can show my usb drive without any problem.

However, I cannot see the device in qemu boot manager or in edk2 shell. the `map -r` show nothing. What did I do wrong here?

Comment: I wasn't able to boot from USB from GPT partition table, but was able to boot when i reformatted USB drive in MBR mode.

Answer (score 0):

ah, my bad. The USB controller was by default USB2, I just change it to USB3. Then it works.